# Django : 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is the Api

```
class UnAssignEmployeeToOrderItemTaskViewSet(
    ResponseViewMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    ):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddOrderItemSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(id=kwargs['order_id'])
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(id=kwargs['order_item_id'], order=order)
            item_task = OrderItemTaskEmployee.objects.get(id=kwargs['task_id'], item=order_item)
            d =  UnAssignEmployeeToOrderItemTaskViewSetSerializer(instance=item_task)
            item_task.assignee = None
            item_task.assigned_at = None
            item_task.save()
            serializer = OrderItemsListSerializer(order_item)
            return self.jp_response(s_code="HTTP_200_OK", data=serializer.data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return self.jp_error_response(
                "HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR", "EXCEPTION", str(e)
            )
```

url

```
router.register(r'(?P<order_id>.+)/items/(?P<order_item_id>.+)/task/(?P<task_id>.+)/unassign',
                UnAssignEmployeeToOrderItemTaskViewSet, 'unassign-order-items-task')
```

But api call returns an error

[image]

I spent a lot of time trying to fix this error. Please give me a solution to overcome this problem